# Typeform How to edit css border radius in embedded typeform

Tags: html, css, typeform

I want to pass styling parameters into embedded Typeform. I have followed their "embedded mode" guide and stored typeform in a DOM element, however when I am trying to edit any css, nothing happens.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on posting your first question.
To embed a Typeform in your website you should use their [embed SDK](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/), it will give you more control over the experience.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can override style by adding external CSS to a Typeform. You should instead change the look and feel directly in the Typeform builder itself.

Best

Comment: Aww, that's too bad Typeform editable looks and feel is very limited in the builder.

Comment: Did you check the template gallery? you can be really creative and adapt the look and feel to your own brand https://www.typeform.com/templates/

Or here you can find a guide to modify a typeform theme: https://www.typeform.com/help/apply-a-theme-to-your-typeform/

Hope it helps :)